# Raising Events seems to have changed

Tags: c#, .net, events, .net-4.5

In a previous version of .NET (I think 3) I used something like this to raise an event with custom `EventArgs`

```
public delegate void NewTitleEventArgs(object sender, string title);
public event NewTitleEventArgs NewTitle;

public class NewTitleEventArgs : EventArgs //Class used to pass data to event consumers when sending notification.
{
    public readonly string NewTitle;
    public NewTitleEventArgs(string Title)
    {
        NewTitle = Title;
    }
}
```

However, it seems I only need to do this now:

```
public delegate void NewTitleEventArgs(object sender, string title);
public event NewTitleEventArgs NewTitle;
```

and totally ignore the class. Is this standard or a new thing?

Comment: Not sure what you mean because that first sample won't compile and you haven't raised the event, only declared it. However, the declaration of `EventHandler<T>` dropped the `T : EventArgs` constraint in .NET 4.5, if that is what you are talking about.

Comment: The code wouldn't compile if the class definition wasn't there. That definitely hasn't changed.

Comment: @CamBruce On the contrary, the code won't compile if the class is there, because it declares two types with the same name (a delegate and a class).

Comment: Wait guys... BOTH compile and BOTH work! I raise the event elsewhere - its the definition I am looking at not the calling.

Comment: @Mike z
Yes mike - that is what I was talking about - thank you.
Change your comment to an Answer and you get the points

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I know what you are talking about and yes there was a change. In [.NET 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and earlier the definition for `EventHandler<TEventArgs>` was

```
public delegate void EventHandler<TEventArgs>(
    Object sender,
    TEventArgs e
)
where TEventArgs : EventArgs
```

However starting in [.NET 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the definition changed to

```
public delegate void EventHandler<TEventArgs>(
    Object sender,
    TEventArgs e
)
```

The only difference being that `TEventArgs` is no longer required to inherit from `EventArgs` so it is now possible to do

```
public event EventHandler<string> NewTitle;
```

Which would let the subscribing member be

```
public void myObject_NewTitle(object sender, string title)
{
   //...
}
```

instead of having some `EventArgs` wrapper with your title inside of it as the only member.

Answer (score 1):

Your first sample doesn't make much sense and won't compile. You're declaring two types with the same name (a delegate and a class both called `NewTitleEventArgs`) and that's not allowed.

Your second sample compiles and works fine, and it will compile in all versions of C# down to C# 1.0. But it doesn't conform to [the framework guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w369ty8x.aspx), so you shouldn't write code like that.

The conforming pattern is to create a class that inherits from `EventArgs` and use that as the second parameter of the delegate.

You would write that like this (I have also fixed some other style issues in the code):

```
public class NewTitleEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string NewTitle { get; private set; }

    public NewTitleEventArgs(string title)
    {
        NewTitle = title;
    }
} 

public delegate void NewTitleEventHandler(object sender, NewTitleEventArgs args);
public event NewTitleEventHandler NewTitle;
```

Since C# 2.0 (released in 2005), you can also use the generic `EventHandler<T>` delegate type to avoid having to declare new delegate type for each event args type:

```
public class NewTitleEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string NewTitle { get; private set; }

    public NewTitleEventArgs(string title)
    {
        NewTitle = title;
    }
} 

public event EventHandler<NewTitleEventArgs> NewTitle;
```

Comment: There is one new change in [.NET 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), in  `EventHandler<T>` the `T` is no-longer required [to be a class derived from `EventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). You can use any class now for the 2nd argument.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Interesting, I didn't know that (I somehow missed the comment by mike z). But I doubt that's what the question is about, it doesn't even mention `EventHandler<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

Your second example is not new either it was there already, the first sample is used to implement your own event argument onto your delegate

e.g.

```
public delegate void NewTitleEventArgs(object sender, string title, myCustomArugment e);
```

public event NewTitleEventArgs NewTitle;

then you need to implement your own myCustomArugment event argument